# Python - is it better practice to use global var or pass to function when variable will only be used on error

Tags: python

I have a aws python lambda with 7 functions. 1 of them is using a variable that is extracted from the payload called file_id. I now need that in another function that is called directly from this function but will only use it on the rare occasion of throwing an error.

eg.

```
def execute(event, context):
    body = get_body(event)
    file_id = get_file_id(body)
    # do some stuff here that generates service_header abd service_payload variable
    call_external_service(service_header, service_payload)
    # do some more stuff here that is irrelevant 

def call_external_service(header, payload)
     # do some irrelevant stuff
     try:
        response = requests.put(
            url, data=payload, headers=headers
        )
    except Exception as e:
         LOGGER.info(
            "Failed request for file_id "
            + str(file_id) # obviously this isn't available wondering is it better to pass in or make global, it will rarely be used.
        )
        send_file_id_to_database(file_id);
```

Is it better practice to send it into the method by adding an extra parameter or is it better to  make it global. It will only be used rarely when another service is down.

Comment: Unless the variable is used by many different functions, and would have to be passed around without being used through lots of function calls, it should probably be a parameter.

Comment: See [Why global variables should be avoided unless necessary](https://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing it in as a parameter is often considered better coding practice for several reasons, one of which being that it's easier to test the function that takes `file_id` as a parameter than if it accessed it as a global.